# PHP - First and last character check

Tags: php, if-statement, logic

I am trying a check in PHP. What I want is to check:

- The first character in a string must be a "["
- The last character in a string must be a "]"

I've written this code (last if statement is what I actually want) to check this but am not getting the result I wanted:

```
$str = "dfgdfg]";

if($str[0] != '[') {
    echo "FIRST NOT EQUAL TO";
}

if(substr($str,-1) != ']') {
    echo "SECOND NOT EQUAL TO";
}


if( ($str[0] != '[') && (substr($str,-1) != ']') ) {
  echo "COND MET!";
}
```

If I run this code I thought that the last if statement would execute however, only the first if statement executes. What is wrong with the logic in the last if statement?

Comment: As per your `$string` does not have `[` so it does echo what is written.second id false as it contains `]` so no echo there. and due to `&&` condition in last if it will only satisfy first condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the last statement set as "AND - && " and should be an "OR - ||"

```
if( ($str[0] != '[') || (substr($str,-1) != ']') ) {
echo "COND MET!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your final `if` statement is checking that the first character of your string is **NOT** a `[`, and the last character is also **NOT** a `]`. If you remove the last `]` from your `$str`, you'll see the `COND MET` output.

```
if( ($str[0] != '[') && (substr($str,-1) != ']') ) {
  echo "COND MET!";
}
```

If you want the check to ensure the string both starts and ends with a `[` and `]`, respectively, you need this:

```
if( ($str[0] == '[') && (substr($str,-1) == ']') ) {
  echo "COND MET!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple RegExr check:

```
if (preg_match('/^\[.*\]$/', $str) {}
```